# Need help http Server and client server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node.js-stream, node.js-client

I have used an application for login, adding friends and chat using node.js and mongoDB.I installed the node.js and monogoDB on ec2 instance. However, I do not know if need to use client server and http server? 
Here is the application that I used  https://github.com/1karthik/Node.js_UserLogin_Template
note: I am new to node.js and mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a "client server". Your http server will serve to your clients some javascript files that will help them to comunicate with your server. If you go in app/public/scripts you can see theese files.

Comment: Thank you. But I have another question, I tried to run the application it works and when I add friends to friends list cannot be displayed. Do you have any idea?